# Socket send/receive issue: second client message never reaches server

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm tryting to send some files from client to server. For that first I'm sending file name and then sending back the same from server to validate on client side. Once validated I'm sending the file size and resending the same for validation. If file size got validated I'm sending file content.

Now the problem is, 2nd send command by server never reaches client correctly. 
Below is my client code for sending and checking response. What I'm doing wrong here.

Server code is simple. It just sends the received buffer by 'send' command.

Client code>>

```
int SendDataAndReadResponse(CString cstData)
{
  //Send data
  send(m_hSocket, (LPCTSTR)cstData, cstData.GetLength(), 0);

  //Read response
  char chBuff[256];
  memset(chBuff, 0, sizeof(chBuff));
  int iReadLength = 0;

  while(true)
  {
    iReadLength = recv(m_hSocket, chBuff, sizeof(chBuff)-1, 0);
    if(iReadLength > 0)
    {
      chBuff[iReadLength] = '\0';
      CString cstrData = CString(chBuff);
      ::PostMessage(this->GetSafeHwnd(), UWM_UPDATE_STATUS, MODE_THROW_LOG, (LPARAM)new CString(cstrData));
    }
    else
    {
      ::PostMessage(this->GetSafeHwnd(), UWM_UPDATE_STATUS, MODE_THROW_LOG, (LPARAM)new CString("-----End of recv----"));
      break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're sure that both machines (client and server) have the same endianess? Usually a prefixed message length is sent in network byte order.

Comment: Currently I'm testing the code with localhost. i.e. both client and server on same pc.

Comment: you do realize you have a memory leak here?   (LPARAM)new CString(cstrData) who deallocates the memory?

Comment: also, did you validated with printf that there is nothing in chBuff?

Comment: @..David. the qus is not about memory leak. Its only a piece of code. delete is in the message handler. And no point of printf as its win32 app.

Answer (score 1):

This code sends *one* thing and then loops reading responses until end of stream or an error occurs. Unless an error does occur, or the server closes the connection at this point, or sends a second response to the same request, it will block forever in the `recv()` call.

NB You can't assume that `recv()` returning `<= 0` indicates "end of recv". It could also indicate an error, which may or may not be fatal to the connection, depending on what it is.

You don't need to construct the `CString` twice. You don't need the `memset()` either: correct use of the count returned by `recv()` is sufficient.

Comment: Yes. I added loop for a bad reason with socket timeout value. But what you  said is perfectly correct as I'm getting the first response with a single call of recv(). Can you tell me one thing. As this is tcp socket is that guranteed that recv() will receive complete data with one single read if the data coming to the socket within buffer read limit?

Comment: You can't assume that: you do need to loop until you have all the data you need. The problem here is not the loop but the termination condition. You need to loop on length, or a known terminating character, etc.

Comment: @PLearner - listen to EJP. The problem gets worse on mobile platforms where data is lost in transit as you are traversing cells. You will need a robust message protocol and handler. Don't rely on mTCP.